# How to figure out the PIDs of my tmux sessions?

Tags: tmux

Figured out the hard way that [starting `tmux` sessions under different sockets are not listed with `tmux ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/744030/85131), as it is only a shortcut for `tmux -L default list-sessions` showing sessions that belong to the `default` socket. (I am using `tmux -L` [to make `tmux` inherit the calling shell's environment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/743817/how-to-start-tmux-in-a-way-that-it-inherits-all-environment-variables-from-the-c).)

`tmux ls` does not show the PIDs of the sessions:

```
$ tmux -L default ls
1: 1 windows (created Thu Mar 30 09:39:31 2023) (attached)

$ tmux -L lofa ls
0: 1 windows (created Tue Apr 25 15:12:00 2023) (attached)
2: 1 windows (created Tue Apr 25 16:25:38 2023)
```

I tried naively to match up the process by start times, and even though I can deduce which session is which as the start times of `lofa`'s sessions do match and the only one left is `default`'s, but the `default` session's time is notably different.

```
$ ps x -o lstart,pid,stat,args f

                 STARTED     PID STAT COMMAND
Tue Apr 25 15:01:27 2023 2387795 S    sshd: lynx-dev@pts/4
Tue Apr 25 15:01:27 2023 2387796 Ss    \_ -bash
Tue Apr 25 15:01:33 2023 2387820 S         \_ bash --rcfile /tmp/nix-shell-2387820-0/rc
Tue Apr 25 16:52:21 2023 2393925 R+            \_ ps x -o lstart,pid,stat,args f
Tue Apr 25 15:00:23 2023 2387609 S    sshd: lynx-dev@pts/1
Tue Apr 25 15:00:23 2023 2387610 Ss    \_ -bash
Tue Apr 25 15:11:51 2023 2389501 S         \_ bash --rcfile /tmp/nix-shell-2389501-0/rc
Tue Apr 25 15:12:00 2023 2391030 S+            \_ tmux -L lofa
Tue Apr 25 14:59:32 2023 2385992 S    sshd: lynx-dev@pts/0
Tue Apr 25 14:59:33 2023 2385998 Ss    \_ -bash
Tue Apr 25 14:59:41 2023 2386007 S+        \_ bash /tmp/nix-shell-2386007-0/rc
Tue Apr 25 14:59:42 2023 2387528 S+            \_ tmux attach
Tue Apr 25 15:12:00 2023 2391032 Ss   tmux -L lofa
Tue Apr 25 15:12:00 2023 2391033 Ss+   \_ -bash
Tue Apr 25 16:25:38 2023 2393553 Ss+   \_ -bash
Tue Jan 24 17:58:29 2023   32710 Ss   tmux
Wed Apr 12 12:56:35 2023 1187196 Ss    \_ -bash
Wed Apr 12 12:57:28 2023 1187935 S         \_ bash --rcfile /run/user/1000/nix-shell-1187935-0/rc
Wed Apr 12 13:00:18 2023 1190971 Sl+           \_ /nix/store/ybmibj2kdfd3m1dq9rl8kcpy23av4c74-vim_configurable-9.0.0609/bin/vim -u /nix/store/7lsixnw74d45g3l6g2nfaqw80fsal5jl-vimrc
Wed Apr 12 13:02:36 2023 1191015 Ss                \_ /nix/store/38db4p333ibll7r1v151yc5f6ms1fr00-bash-interactive-5.2-p15/bin/bash
Wed Apr 12 13:02:42 2023 1191725 S+                    \_ bash --rcfile /run/user/1000/nix-shell-1191725-0/rc
Tue Jan 24 17:54:53 2023   22116 Ss   /lib/systemd/systemd --user
Tue Jan 24 17:54:53 2023   22117 S     \_ (sd-pam)
Thu Jan 26 02:42:42 2023   98296 SLs   \_ /usr/bin/gpg-agent --supervised
Tue Apr 11 21:08:13 2023 1178866 Ss    \_ /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
```

Answer (score 1):

`tmux list-sessions` accepts a format string (see ["FORMATS" section](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#FORMATS) in the man page):

```
$ tmux ls  -F 'socket_path: #{socket_path} | session_name: #{session_name} | server_pid: #{pid} | pane_pid: #{pane_pid}'
socket_path: /tmp/tmux-1000/default | session_name: 1 | server_pid: 32710 | pane_pid: 1187196

$ tmux -L lofa ls  -F 'socket_path: #{socket_path} | session_name: #{session_name} | server_pid: #{pid} | pane_pid: #{pane_pid}'
socket_path: /tmp/tmux-1000/lofa | session_name: 0 | server_pid: 2391032 | pane_pid: 2391033
socket_path: /tmp/tmux-1000/lofa | session_name: 2 | server_pid: 2391032 | pane_pid: 2393553
```

Or with newlines:

```
$ tmux -L lofa ls -F \
> 'socket_path: #{socket_path}
> └── session_name: #{session_name} | server_pid: #{pid} | pane_pid: #{pane_pid}'

socket_path: /tmp/tmux-1000/lofa
└── session_name: 0 | server_pid: 2391032 | pane_pid: 2391033
socket_path: /tmp/tmux-1000/lofa
└── session_name: 2 | server_pid: 2391032 | pane_pid: 2393553
```